# Is Legion (David Haller) still alive?

Tags: marvel, x-men, psychic

I really enjoyed Legion’s character in the recent run of X-Men. But in the end

> he disappears, after finally becoming whole, into Ruth’s head.

But it hasn’t gone on to explain whether it’s really him or just

> some sort of psychic residue left over from their previous connection.

And if he is

> in Blindfold’s head

do we think he'll be allowed out again?

Comment: Jeez - spoiler alert!

Comment: Oh hardly! I didnt reveal any of the story itself. That's like saying "the titanic Sinks!" is a spoiler.

Comment: @Madrox: sure, X-Men is just an adaptation of the America’s famous mutant period in history.

Comment: Didnt realise I could block text for spoioers. Thanks Mr White